# Hive query to read row and put it into table column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am creating hive table having sales records of different country date wise.

```
create external table sales_records (sales_date string, country string, sales bigint)
--partitioned by (country string)
-- sorted by (sales_date)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

I inserted record in it.

```
insert into sales_records values 
    ("2018-01-01", "us", 5000) ,
    ("2018-01-02", "us", 500) ,
    ("2018-01-03", "us", 5500) ,
    ("2018-01-04", "us", 1500) ,
    ("2018-01-01", "ind", 500) ,
    ("2018-01-03", "ind", 500) ,
    ("2018-01-04", "ind", 5500) ,
    ("2018-01-06", "ind", 1500) ;
```

Now I need records in a way that output must contain:

us_sales = sales in us at date

ind_sales = sales in ind at date

difference = | us_sales - ind_sales|

```
sales_date  | us_sales |  ind_sales  | difference
--------------------------------------------------
2018-01-01  |  5000    |   500       |  4500
-------------------------------------------------
2018-01-02  |  500     |     0       |   500
-------------------------------------------------
2018-01-03  |  5500    |   500       |  5000
-------------------------------------------------
2018-01-04  |  1500    |  5500       |  4000
-------------------------------------------------
2018-01-06  |     0    |  1500       |  1500
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` with aggregation by `sales_date`:

```
select sales_date, us_sales,  ind_sales, abs(us_sales - ind_sales) as difference
from 
(
select sales_date, 
       sum(case when country='ind' then sales end)  as ind_sales,
       sum(case when country='us'  then sales end)  as us_sales
  from sales_records 
group by sales_date
)s
order by sales_date;
```